# Linq query no longer ordered properly after .Distinct() used

Tags: .net, linq

Below is a simple Linq query I am using to fill in a jquery `autocomplete` list. The list is ordered properly until after the `.Distinct()` method gets called. Can anyone clue me in as to why or a way to remove duplicates from the list and keep it in order?

```
    public JsonResult OverrideSearch(string term)
    {
        var drm = from    d in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                  where   d.DrmTerrDesc.Contains(term)
                  orderby d.DrmTerrDesc
                  select  d.DrmTerrDesc;

        drm = drm.Distinct();

        return Json(drm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Why not just `Distinct` it first, then order it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply ordering after distinct:

```
public JsonResult OverrideSearch(string term)
{
    var drm = db.ZipCodeTerritory
                .Where(d => d.DrmTerrDesc.Contains(term))
                .Select(d => d.DrmTerrDesc)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(d => d);

    return Json(drm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Or with query syntax (I don't like to mix query and method syntax):

```
public JsonResult OverrideSearch(string term)
{
    var drm = from d in db.ZipCodeTerritory
              where d.DrmTerrDesc.Contains(term)
              select  d.DrmTerrDesc;

    drm = drm.Distinct();

    return Json(drm.OrderBy(d => d), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

BTW there is a remark on [Queryable.Distinct](http://Queryable.Distinct) method at MSDN which tells that it usually returns unordered sequence:

> The query behavior that occurs as a result of executing an expression
>   tree that represents calling Distinct(IQueryable)
>   depends on the implementation of the type of the source parameter. The
>   expected behavior is that it returns an unordered sequence of the
>   unique items in source.